# How to put match.group() text into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, python-re

I am using re to filter down a bunch of text to information I need. I am now able to print the two pieces of information I need from each line in the text with match.group().

match.group(1) is a number and match.group(4) is a string. For each line (iteration through the for loop) I need match.group(1) to be added to one column in a dataframe and match.group(4) to be added to another column.

Here is the code (the print statement at the bottom needs to be replaced with the code to add each element to the dataframe):

```
finalText = re.search(r'19\s+domestic and stock rights(.*?)20\s+native title rights', rawText, flags=re.S | re.I).group(

pattern = re.compile('(\d+)( ML/year )(in the |the )([\w \/\(\)]+)')

df = pd.DataFrame()

for line in finalText.splitlines():
    matches = re.finditer(pattern, line)

    for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    print (match.group(1) +","+ match.group(4))
```

and mathc
match.group(1) is a number and match.group(4) is a location so an example of the dataframe would be:

```
Water Usage    Town
55             York
718            Holst
7              Poke
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data DataFrame? Or what is `rawText` ?

Comment: How would you know to which row to add it to?

Comment: Just a new row for each line or each iteration

Comment: rawText is the text file I am filtering down using re

Comment: Can you add input data? Not output, because cannot test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create list of tuples and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
out = []
for line in finalText.splitlines():
    matches = re.finditer(pattern, line)

    for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
        out.append((match.group(1), match.group(4)))
        
df = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=['Water Usage','Town'])
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add to a new DF then:

You first initiate a new DF outside the loop:

```
new_df = pd.dataframe(columns=['match1','match4'])
```

and inside the loop:

```
row = [match.group(1), match.group(4)]
new_df.loc[len(new_df)] = row
```

if it is to the existing DF - replace new_df with df in the two last line codes

Comment: I get the error "cannot set a frame with no defined columns"

Comment: I think Jezrael above solution answers your question

Comment: @Dhar_ - anyhow, I have fixed my answer as well

Comment: @gtomer - One idea - updating empty DataFrame is not recommneded, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24871316/2901002)